# Is a new branch necessary before git cherry pick?

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-commit, git-cherry-pick

I've been following this example [here](http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/rebase-from-the-ground-up/using-git-cherry-pick-to-simulate-git-rebase.html), and it shows that you create a temporary branch before you use `git cherry-pick`, and then you cherry pick onto that temporary branch.

In the example, the temporary branch is called `newbar`, and it branches off from `foo`.

Is it necessary to have the temporary branch?  Or can you just cherry pick from `foo`?  The example doesn't make it clear the purpose of this temporary branch.

Comment: If you did the cherry-pick with `foo`, then foo would be pointing to E'. The new branch is used so that `foo` is still pointing to H after all is said and done.

Comment: The whole point of the example, though, is to show how you can use cherry-pick to simulate rebase. If you just want to cherry-pick commits onto a branch, you can check out that branch and use `git cherry-pick A`, with `A` being the commit hash...no need for a temporary branch.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't ***need*** to have a separate branch.  This is perfectly legal:

```
$ git log --decorate --oneline --graph --all
* f1188b1 (HEAD -> master) commit3
* 90a233e commit2
* f167481 commit1
```

Then while still in the single and only branch `master`:

```
$ git cherry-pick 90a233e
```

The catch here is that it's quite possible to have a conflict (below is sample output after a cherry-pick):

```
error: could not apply 90a233e... commit2
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

Simply handle and resolve, as per `git-status`:

```
$ git status
On branch master
You are currently cherry-picking commit 90a233e.
  (fix conflicts and run "git cherry-pick --continue")
  (use "git cherry-pick --abort" to cancel the cherry-pick operation)

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        both modified:   file1.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Basically you'll fix your conflict, and then add the changes to the index and run `$ git cherry-pick --continue` to complete the cherry pick operation.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to create a new branch for cherry-picking. The reason the example does it is because is simulating the `rebase` command.

[This example](http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/rebase-from-the-ground-up/cherry-picking-explained.html) is clearer

> If you were at node H in this graph, and you typed git cherry-pick E
>   (yes, you'd actually type part or all of the SHA for the commit, but
>   for simplicity's sake, I'll just use the labels that are already
>   here), you'd wind up with a copy of commit E—let's call it "E prime"
>   or E'—that pointed to H as its parent, like so:
>
> [image]
>
> The important thing to notice here is that Git has copied changes made
>   in one place, and replayed them somewhere else.